# Remove user endpoints in Django rest auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django rest auth for user account handling. For updating user info i have created custom endpoints, So i don't need the djnago-rest-auth generated endpoints `/rest-auth/user/ (GET, PUT, PATCH)`. How can i remove these endpoints?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("rest_auth.urls"), name="user-auth"),
    path('register', include('rest_auth.registration.urls'), name="user-auth-registration"),
    path('<uid>/', views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name="user-profile"),
]
```

**Edit**

I want to use all other urls of rest-auth like login, register, etc. But i just dont want the `/rest-auth/user/` as described [here](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html).

Comment: Provide your urls.py

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@bodoubleu 's answer didn't work, So i added them manually.

```
from rest_auth.views import (
    LoginView, LogoutView, PasswordChangeView,
    PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', include('rest_auth.registration.urls'), name="user-auth-registration"),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name="user-login"),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='user-logout'),
    path('password/change/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='rest_password_change'),
    path('password/reset', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset'),
    path('password/reset/confirm/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset_confirm'),
    path('<uid>/', views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name="user-profile"),
]
```

Comment: Please how are you able to view user profile with id. And are you using token or sessions ? I would really appreciate your response

Comment: @King I am using token auth. About viewing user profile, i don't think its related to this question. Please ask another question i will answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should work.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', django.views.defaults.page_not_found),
    path('', include("rest_auth.urls"), name="user-auth"),
    path('register', include('rest_auth.registration.urls'), name="user-auth-registration"),
    path('<uid>/', views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name="user-profile"),
]
```

If not you can manually define all the [`rest_auth.urls`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/3b80fcbca9b3d9f9f918cda27db86ee0869556cd/rest_auth/urls.py) in your url patterns